# How to shift value of column as new variable name?

Tags: sas, formatting, transform, transformation, transpose

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
ID   Model_Value Count_Model
111      24          2
222      12          9
234      88          6
111      88          8
222      24          10
222      88          17
```

I want it to look like this:

```
ID   Model_12 Model_24 Model_88
111      0       2       8
222      9       10      17
234      0       0       6
```

I don't think I am searching online for the correct terms, I thought initially a transform might work but I still want the row to represent the ID not the model.

How do I go about creating this output from what I have?

Comment: You should look at `PROC TRANSPOSE`

Comment: oops yes, I meant transpose. I looked at transpose but looks like that just flips it and I don't want to actually flip the data I want the ID to stay as the row. I will take a second look. Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while since I used it but the `ID` and `BY` keywords let you keep ID where you want it to be, `VAR` is used for the `Count_Model` values and there's a `PREFIX=` option which would allow you to tell it to give the columns the `Model_` prefix. Good luck!

Comment: Hey! I just posted the answer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I have two additional questions: 1)Do you happen to know if there is an option to make the missing points zeros in the transpose function or do I have to make another dataset just for that. 2) For prefix is there a way to include an underscore before the number? I would like it to be Model_Value_24 and not Model_Value24. You can see my output below and run the code as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure about 1) sorry, but for question 2, the value given in prefix is simply the text that is the prefix, so you can have whatever you like, `prefix=banana` will give you `banana24` etc. All you need to do in your case is use `prefix = model_value_`. This behaviour is unusual, as you would expect to have to quote the value, but SAS has its quirks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I believe this is it! Thank you @mjsqu !!
I was able to do this with the help of this link: http://www.sascommunity.org/mwiki/images/d/dd/PROC_Transpose_slides.pdf

```
data test_transpose ;
input @1  ID_P  @6 Model_Value @18 Count_Model ;
cards;
111  24          2
222  12          9
234  88          6
111  88          8
222  24          10
222  88          17
run;
proc print data=test_transpose;
run;
proc sort data=test_transpose out=test_transpose_S;
    By ID_P;
run;

proc transpose
 data = test_transpose_S 
 out = test_transpose_result (drop=_name_)
 prefix=Model_Value;
 var Count_Model;
 BY ID_P;
 id Model_Value;
run;
proc print data=test_transpose_result ;
run;
```

Output of the original sorted dataset and the transpose!
[image]